# Law of propagation

Tags: probability-or-statistics

If i have weight average of independent variables how i should calculate uncertainty. E.g
Function F=( w1x1 + w2x2 )/w1+ w2
And followed errors
For w1 error e1
For w2 error e2
For x1 error e3
For x2 error e4

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

As @jose says, using [`Around`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around) as in my original answer assumes that the two `w1` expressions are uncorrelated. A better approach is to use [`AroundReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AroundReplace):

```
r = AroundReplace[
    (w1 x1+w2 x2)/(w1+w2),
    {w1->Around[w1,e1],w2->Around[w2,e2],x1->Around[x1,e3],x2->Around[x2,e4]}
];
r //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\text{w1} \text{x1}+\text{w2} \text{x2}}{\text{w1}+\text{w2}}\pm
>    \sqrt{\text{e1}^2 \left(\frac{\text{x1}}{\text{w1}+\text{w2}}-\frac{\text{w1}
>    \text{x1}+\text{w2} \text{x2}}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}\right)^2+\text{e2}^2
>    \left(\frac{\text{x2}}{\text{w1}+\text{w2}}-\frac{\text{w1} \text{x1}+\text{w2}
>    \text{x2}}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}\right)^2+\frac{\text{e3}^2
>    \text{w1}^2}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}+\frac{\text{e4}^2
>    \text{w2}^2}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}}$

After simplification:

```
r //Simplify //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\text{w1} \text{x1}+\text{w2} \text{x2}}{\text{w1}+\text{w2}}\pm
>    \sqrt{\frac{(\text{x1}-\text{x2})^2 \left(\text{e1}^2 \text{w2}^2+\text{e2}^2
>    \text{w1}^2\right)+\text{e3}^2 \text{w1}^2 (\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2+\text{e4}^2
>    \text{w2}^2 (\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^4}}$

**Original answer**

You can use [`Around`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around):

```
(Around[w1,e1]Around[x1,e3]+Around[w2,e2]Around[x2,e4])/(Around[w1,e1]+Around[w2,e2])//TeXForm
```

> $\frac{\text{w1} \text{x1}+\text{w2} \text{x2}}{\text{w1}+\text{w2}}\pm \sqrt{(\text{w1}
>    \text{x1}+\text{w2} \text{x2})^2 \left|
>    \frac{\sqrt{\text{e1}^2+\text{e2}^2}}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}\right|
>    ^2+\frac{\text{e1}^2 \text{x1}^2+\text{e2}^2 \text{x2}^2+\text{e3}^2
>    \text{w1}^2+\text{e4}^2 \text{w2}^2}{(\text{w1}+\text{w2})^2}}$

Comment: Expressing the computation this way assumes that the two copies of w1 are uncorrelated, for example. I'd say that using AroundReplace[expr, rules] would be more appropriate, to keep the correlation.

Comment: @jose Great point! I’ll change my answer accordingly when I get a chance

Comment: but what if I do have more variables?F= (∑wixi)/(∑wi) with errors ei...